# bird traveling to a nest wants to save energy

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

This is a multiple choice question in one of tests I just wrote and I did not know the answer to it. I was just stuck on this during the test. It is a very weird question, one I find to be impossible.

Here it goes:

> Scientists have determined some species of birds tend to avoid flights
>   over large bodies of water during daylight hours. It is believed that
>   more energy is required to fly over water than land because air rises
>   over land and falls over water during day. A bird with these
>   tendencies is released from an island that is 5 km  form the nearest
>   point B on a straight shoreline, flies to point C on the shoreline,
>   and then flies along the shoreline to its nesting area D. Assume that
>   the brid instinctively chooses a path that will minimize its energy
>   expenditure. Points B and D are 13 km apart.
>
> If it takes 2 times as much energy to fly over water as land, what is
>   the minimum amount of total energy that the bird could expend
>   returning to its nesting area?
>
> a) 2.88 units $\phantom{abcd}$ b) 21.66 units $\phantom{abcd}$ c) 23.00 units $\phantom{abcd}$ d) 27.85 units

I have no idea how to do this question because it makes absolutely no sense to me. I have sat and thought but I just am not getting anywhere.

Comment: You must be leaving something out. The question is unanswerable as it stands. What is a unit of energy?

Comment: The answer is b). I have to agree with TonyK that the question is pretty badly formulated. Did they at least put a drawing next to it?

Comment: That is exactly what I am thinking....energy is joules what the heck are they referring to :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: diagram]

This is a minimization problem, and you have to minimize

$$E(x) = 2\cdot |AC| + |CD|$$

where $x = |BC|$, with $C \in[B,D]$, $A\hat{B}D=90°$, $|AB|=5$ and $|BD|=13$.

That is,

$$E(x) = 2 \cdot \sqrt{5^2+x^2}+13-x$$

Take the derivative of this and find the zeros in $[0, 13]$, etc., giving the multiple choice answer (b).

Comment: Heh, it's not to scale, but I wanted to figure out how to make & post a drawing. ;)))

Comment: how do u guys add the math symbols and drawing on this forum?

Comment: thanks so much if possible can you please explain how u got the 2* |AC| + |CD|?

Comment: @Nadal: See [Markdown Editing Help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). For images, there's a "picture icon" in edit mode that lets you link to or upload an image.

Comment: @Nadal this is because travel over sea ($|AC|$) is twice as expensive over land($|CD|$)

Comment: @Nadal: PS about math symbols ... You can right click a math expression and choose "Show Source" to see the source code that's producing it. (The source it shows doesn't include the enclosing $-signs, though.) Also, I like to use [this page](http://mathurl.com/) for testing, and I find much of [this WP formula help page](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Formula) to be useful.

Comment: @ratchet freak: Because of [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/are-uploaded-images-preserved-in-the-se-system), I edited your answer to put the definition of $x$ in text, in case the image-link expires (as apparently is likely, eventually). I hope you don't mind my doing these edits myself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the distance from where the bird starts to $C$.  Using the Pythagorean Theorem, one finds that the distance from $C$ to $D$ is $13-\sqrt{x^2-25}$ . Setting the energy expenditure factor over the shore equal to $a\,{\rm units\over km}$, the energy used is 
$$
E(x)=2ax + a \cdot(13-\sqrt{x^2-25}).
$$

What you need to do is find the minimum value of $E$ over the interval $[5,\sqrt{194}]$ (if the bird  first flies to $B$, then $x=5$ ; if the bird flies straight to $D$, then $x=\sqrt{194}$).

So:

Set $E'(x)=0$ and find any solutions in $[5,\sqrt{194}]$.

Evaluate $E$ at the solutions found above, at $x=5$, and at $x=\sqrt{194}$.

Select the smallest of these numbers.  This will give you the minimum energy expenditure if the energy expenditure over land is $a\,{\rm units\over km}$.

By the way, the problem seems ill-posed, since they did not tell you what the energy expenditure over land was (I presume they took $a=1$).

Comment: er the shore $[BD]$ is straight and $C$ is a point on that shore so $|CD|=|BD|-|CB|=13-x$ with $|AC|^2=|AB|^2+|CB|^2=25+x^2$

Comment: I made exactly the same mistake the first time through! 13 is the distance from $B$ to $D$, not the distance from the island to $D$. So your twelves should be thirteens, and your thirteeens should be $\sqrt {194}$s.